# "Unknown type encountered" when using generic type in Firebase GenericTypeIndicator

Tags: java, android, generics, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to create class with generic type where I create function to read list of entities. And I know that I have 2 ways to do this: (#1) by read each entity in a loop or (#2) create a map of entities directly.

2nd way looks more efficient but unfortunately `GenericTypeIndicator` doesn't work with generic type - it returns `IllegalStateException: Unknown type encountered: T` when I use it in code:

```java
Map<String, T> entityMap =
    dataSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, T>>() {});
```

So:

1. Is there any way to read generic type of entities directly into a map? (#2)
2. Or just they aren't any significant difference in performance when just read entities in a loop (#1)?

```java
public class SomeClass<T extends KeyEntity> {

    private final Class<T> mGenericClass;
    private final String mRefKey;

    public SomeClass(Class<T> clazz, String refKey) {
        mGenericClass = clazz;
        mRefKey = refKey;
    }

    public class KeyEntity {
        private String mKey;

        public KeyEntity() {}

        public String getKey() {
            return mKey;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            mKey = key;
        }
    }

    public interface EntityListListener<T> {
        abstract public void onEntityListLoaded(List<T> entity);
    }

    public void loadAll(final EntityListListener<T> entityListListener) {
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FireDbUtils.getReference(mRefKey);
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<T> entityList = new ArrayList<>((int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

            // #1 - read each entity in a loop
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                T entity = dataSnapshot.getValue(mGenericClass);
                entity.setKey(childSnapshot.getKey());
                entityList.add(entity);
            }

            // #2 - read all entity into a map
            // GenericTypeIndicator doesn't like generic type
            // if used, it returns "IllegalStateException: Unknown type encountered: T"
            Map<String, T> entityMap 
                = dataSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, T>>() {});
            for (Map.Entry<String, T> pair : entityMap.entrySet()) {
                T entity = pair.getValue();
                entity.setKey(pair.getKey());
                entityList.add(entity);
            }

            entityListListener.onEntityListLoaded(entityList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

eg. data:

```
{
    carList: {
        carKey1: {
            name: "wife car"
        },
        carKey2: {
            name: "my best car in the world ever"
        }
    },
    garageList: {
        garageKey1: {
            name: "house garage"
        },
        garageKey2: {
            name: "top secret garage under main garage"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ParameterizedType to find a generic class object

```
 ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
 //all generic classes      
 Type[] args = type.getActualTypeArguments();

 Class<T> genericClass = (Class<T>) args[0];

 T entity = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericClass);
```